# error with if else statement

Tags: android, if-statement

I was some problem with the if else statement, please its support

```
if (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[6]) &&            
                    (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[6]) || (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[7]) || (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[8]) || (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[9]) || (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[10]) || (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[11]) || (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[12]) || (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[13]) || (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[14]) || (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[15])|| 
                            (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[6]) || (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[7]) || (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[8]) || (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[9]) || (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[10]) || (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[11]) || (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[12]) || (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[13]) || (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[14]) || (btn2.getText().toString().equals(myString[15])|| 
                                    (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[6]) || (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[7]) || (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[8]) || (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[9]) || (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[10]) || (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[11]) || (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[12]) || (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[13]) || (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[14]) || (btn3.getText().toString().equals(myString[15])|| 
                                            (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[6]) || (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[7]) || (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[8]) || (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[9]) || (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[10]) || (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[11]) || (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[12]) || (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[13]) || (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[14]) || (btn4.getText().toString().equals(myString[15])|| 
                                                    (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[6]) || (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[7]) || (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[8]) || (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[9]) || (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[10]) || (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[11]) || (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[12]) || (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[13]) || (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[14]) || (btn5.getText().toString().equals(myString[15])|| 
                                                            (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[6]) || (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[7]) || (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[8]) || (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[9]) || (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[10]) || (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[11]) || (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[12]) || (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[13]) || (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[14]) || (btn01.getText().toString().equals(myString[15]) 


                    )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
            } 

            else if (btn1.getText().toString() == (btn2.getText().toString())
                (btn1.getText().toString() == (btn3.getText().toString())||
                        (btn1.getText().toString() == (btn4.getText().toString())||
                                (btn1.getText().toString() == (btn5.getText().toString())||
                                        (btn1.getText().toString() == (btn01.getText().toString())||
                                                (btn2.getText().toString() == (btn3.getText().toString())||
                                                        (btn2.getText().toString() == (btn4.getText().toString())||
                                                                (btn2.getText().toString() == (btn5.getText().toString())||
                                                                        (btn2.getText().toString() == (btn01.getText().toString())||
                                                                                (btn3.getText().toString() == (btn4.getText().toString())||
                                                                                        (btn3.getText().toString() == (btn5.getText().toString())||
                                                                                                (btn3.getText().toString() == (btn01.getText().toString())||
                                                                                                        (btn4.getText().toString() == (btn5.getText().toString())||
                                                                                                                (btn4.getText().toString() == (btn01.getText().toString())||
                                                                                                                        (btn5.getText().toString() == (btn01.getText().toString()))))))))))))))))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "something same", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
            }
            else (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[0])||
                    (btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[1])||(btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[2])||(btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[3])||(btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[4])||(btn1.getText().toString().equals(myString[5])))))))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

if the statement is executed that appear only "something same". what should I add from the code above?

Comment: Man... no offense pretended, but your code sucks.

Comment: What is wrong with my code? I tried to make a puzzle with lots of buttons and if else statement.:D

Comment: If you look at your code and do not feel a chills, you should go to the doctor.

Comment: I consider it a compliment. . :D

Comment: Sorry, but your code does suck.  How do you expect anyone to debug it (including you it seems)?  How about a for loop?

Comment: And here's a clue:  "btn1.getText().toString() == (btn2.getText().toString()" can never be true.

Comment: I just tried that on my mind, and it seems I was wrong, yeah, I'll try it. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first.... `else if (btn1.getText().toString() == (btn2.getText().toString())....`

Use `.equals()` to compare String..and use else if ledder instead of one else if then you can check some problems...